# mysql stored procedure not found

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have create a mysql stored procedure and it correctly works if I call it (from MySQL Workbench) this way:

```
call sp_testACL('#-10$+00/00/00;14 #-1$+00/00/00;0 #1$+00/00/00;0 #-2$+00/00/00;14 #-73$+00/00/00;14',3885,'#3885#-9#-80#-10#-70#-14#','89890/0004',@valore);
```

When I try to use it within a select statement the response is:

> "FUNCTION papamysql.SP_TESTACL does not exist".

by the way I call it like this:

```
select * 
from mytable
where SP_TESTACL('#-10$+00/00/00;14 #-1$+00/00/00;0 #1$+00/00/00;0 #-2$+00/00/00;14 #-73$+00/00/00;14','3885','#3885#-9#-80#-10#-70#-14#','89890/0004','valore')>0;
```

Comment: Functions and stored procedures are used in different contexts. To use `sp_testACL` as an expression inside your query, it would need to have been defined via `CREATE FUNCTION` returning a scalar value http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-function.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried 
select * 
from mytable
where dbo.SP_TESTACL('#-10$+00/00/00;14 #-1$+00/00/00;0 #1$+00/00/00;0 #-2$+00/00/00;14 #-73$+00/00/00;14','3885','#3885#-9#-80#-10#-70#-14#','89890/0004','valore')>0;

select * 
from mytable
where dbo.databasename.SP_TESTACL('#-10$+00/00/00;14 #-1$+00/00/00;0 #1$+00/00/00;0 #-2$+00/00/00;14 #-73$+00/00/00;14','3885','#3885#-9#-80#-10#-70#-14#','89890/0004','valore')>0;

select * 
from mytable
where userthatcreatedprocedureid.databasename.SP_TESTACL('#-10$+00/00/00;14 #-1$+00/00/00;0 #1$+00/00/00;0 #-2$+00/00/00;14 #-73$+00/00/00;14','3885','#3885#-9#-80#-10#-70#-14#','89890/0004','valore')>0;

You may have to specify the user and database depending on how you created the procedure and who you are running it as.

Comment: That will access your procedure but unless you are passing field names from mytable I have no idea of the outcome.